# TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

Tags: python, list, pycharm, openpyxl

Всех привствую! Ошибка в коде из трех строк

```
import openpyxl
wb=openpyxl.load_workbook('example.xlsx')
wb.sheetnames()
```

Возвращает следующую ошибку:Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/***/PycharmProjects/untitled1/venv/1.py", line 3, in 
    wb.sheetnames()
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sheetnames` — это не метод, а атрибут, поэтому его не нужно вызывать.

```py
import openpyxl

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('example.xlsx')
wb.sheetnames  # Список
```